# how can i get data from a single cell [which has more than 3 words(data)] in the database table and set it into 3 jTextFields?

Tags: java, database, jtable

I want to get data from a database table which has 3 columns. There are more than 3 words in each cell.
In the 2nd column which was entered by 3 text fields. The 3 fields are Brand,Name,quantity. I can't say how many words will be there in one field.
It can be one,two or three. So I have tried to put split, but that doesn't do what I want.

Final purpose is when I select a `jTable row` I want to set it into the `jTextFields`.

here is my code :

```
try {
        //Statement s = DB.somak2().createStatement();
        DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        //ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from rawmat");

        int y = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

        id1.setText(dt.getValueAt(y, 0).toString());
        brand.setText(dt.getValueAt(y, 1).toString());
        quantity.setText(dt.getValueAt(y, 2).toString());
        Price.setText(dt.getValueAt(y, 3).toString());
        if (dt.getValueAt(y, 4).toString().equals("Yes")) {
            jCheckBox1.setSelected(true);

        } else if (dt.getValueAt(y, 4).toString().equals("No")) {
            jCheckBox2.setSelected(true);
        }

        if (dt.getValueAt(y, 5).toString().equals("1")) {
            jCheckBox3.setSelected(true);
        } else if (dt.getValueAt(y, 5).toString().equals("0")) {

            jCheckBox4.setSelected(true);
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There are 2 more text fields along with brand, but there is only one table column for 3 texfields (including brand) to get and set data.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment as I don't have enough rep, I am posting here. You must post the code here till what you have tried.

How the column fields are separated? By comma, space or what?

Create a List of String. Then split the string(you get from ReslutSet) based on the delimiter.
Then using loop iterating up to the size of list and you can create JTextField and add the data to textfields.

```
List<String> fielddata = new ArrayList<String>();
fielddata = Arrays.asList(header.split("\\s*" +(your delimeter separating each words here)+ "\\s*"));
```

Comment: I couldn't get what your code exactly says.i need bit more explanation. Column fields are separated by spaces.I have updated my question.please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your question, I'm going to assume you want to collect data from a row?

Try:

```
public String brand;
public String name;
public String quantity;

public void setStringsFromDB() {
  /*
   * getRow and getColumn should work here.
   */
}
```

That should work.. To put it into a JTextField use the [JTextField.setText(String text)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) (Links to JTextComponent.setText() which JTextField inherits) method.

Edit:
I'm not sure of the problem anymore, but try using:

```
brand.setText((String) dt.getValueAt(y, 1));
```

What I'm trying to point out is,

```
(String) dt.getValueAt(y, 1)
```

EDIT 2:

So you want to fill the columns of that row with what is entered into the text box? You are probably better off using 3 JTextFields (Assuming items, Brand, Name, Quantity. You can add more text fields for more items). Here's an example:

```
JTextButton button = new JTextButton("Add items to list");
JTextField brand = new JTextField("Enter brand name here...");
JTextField name = new JTextField("Enter item name here...");
JTextField quantity = new JTextField("Enter desired quantity here...");
JTable jTable1 = new JTable(); // I'm not sure about JTables. but you should already have this...

public Constructor() {
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
      jTable1.setItem(row, 0, brand.getText());
      jTable1.setItem(row, 1, name.getText());
      jTable1.setItem(row, 2, quantity.getText());
      // Don't take my word for those methods, you might need to check the JavaDoc... (link at the bottom.)
    }
  });
}
```

[JTable JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

CONT:

You might want to be scanning one JTextField? If so, do some research on the following:

- Scanner
- Scanner.useDelimiter
- JTextField
- JTable

Comment: sorry this is not exactly what i meant.please check the question which i updated.

Comment: Updated. I hope this helped.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't. to be exact.. this is how i save data into that column : String sq = brand.getText() + " " + jTextField2.getText() + " " + jTextField3.getText(); s2.executeUpdate("insert into materialmaster values('" + s7 + "','" + sq + "','" + cb1 + "')"); what i want is to set data which saved into a single column cell through sq variable. it should be set into brand,jTextField2 & jTextField3. please help.

Comment: Updated. There are more complex ways which is what you might be wanting to do. I am just editing it again with the way I'm thinking you might be speaking of..